# python - find shortest path between 2points(cords) using recursion

Tags: python

i want to create a recursion function that will get list of cords(x,y) and the list lenght so it will return the shortest path between the 2 cords(adjacent indexes)

for example the function will get the list of lists:
`[ [1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [4,5] ]` with lenght `4`
and will return shortest path using `d=√((x_2-x_1)²+(y_2-y_1)²)` formula

I know it's ineffective, thanks for the help!

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.